# How to check the units (days, weeks, months or years) of a subscription period in SKProductDiscount?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, storekit

Apple documentation:

[image]

Here I am able to get the number of units. How do I check if these units are days, weeks, months or years?

I couldn't find anything in the apple documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subscriptionPeriod` property is an instance of [`SKProductSubscriptionPeriod`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsubscriptionperiod).

This class has two properties:

- `numberOfUnits`
- `unit`

The `unit` property has an enumeration value that you can use to determine whether `numberOfUnits` refers to days, weeks, months or years.

Comment: Worth noting that `unit` is not always what you expect. For example, I have a weekly subscription but the `unit` returns `day` and `numberOfUnits` is 7. Given `week` is a value of `unit` and that is what one would expect to be returned.